# Tensorflow Print fixing shape issues?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm running across a very weird issue and was hoping to get someone who might be a bit more familiar. I'm attempting a basic LSTM to do some binary classification with the following coding:

```
class FakeData(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.x = np.random.randint(4, size=(n, 90, 4))
        blah = np.random.randint(2, size=(n))
        self.y = np.zeros((n,2))
        self.y[:,0] = blah
        self.y[:,1] = 1 - blah
        self.mask = np.arange(n)
        self.cnt = 0
        self.n = n

    def getdata(self, n):
        if self.cnt + n > self.n:
            np.randoom.shuffle(self.mask)
            self.cnt = 0
        mask = self.mask[self.cnt : self.cnt + n]
        return self.x[mask], self.y[mask]

n_data = 10000
batch_size = 10
fd = FakeData(n_data)
n_units = 200
n_classes = 2

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 90, 4])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, n_classes])
dropout = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

w_out = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_units, n_classes]))
b_out = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_classes]))

lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(n_units)
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm, output_keep_prob=1.0 - dropout)

new_x = tf.unstack(x, 90, 1)
new_x = tf.Print(new_x, [tf.shape(new_x)], message='newx is: ')
output, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, new_x, dtype=tf.float32)
output = tf.Print(output, [tf.shape(output)], message='output is: ')

logits = tf.matmul(output[-1], w_out) + b_out
logits = tf.Print(logits, [tf.shape(logits)], message='logits is: ')
preds = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, 
    labels=y_))
training = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(loss)

correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(preds, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, tf.float32))

#
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(10):
        batch_x, batch_y = fd.getdata(batch_size)
        sess.run([training], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y_: batch_y, dropout: 0})
        if i % 100 == 0:
            print "Accuracy {}".format(accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: batch_x, 
                y_: batch_y, dropout: 0}))
```

The specific question I have is, for some reason, when I run the code without the tf.Print lines, I get some sort of weird shape transformation error
`ValueError: Dimension must be 2 but is 3 for 'transpose' (op: 'Transpose') with shapes: [?,4], [3].`
on line
`output, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, new_x, dtype=tf.float32)`

However, when I include the tf.Print lines, it correctly logs the shapes and is able to run the whole session. Am I missing something?

For clarity, the shapes should be:
input: n x 90 x 4
new_x: 90 x n x 4
output: 90 x n x 200
logits: n x 2

Comment: Turns out, a lot of old RNN examples floating around use unstack. However, that turns it into a list of tensors, which dynamic_rnn cannot take as input. The print was converting it from a list of 2d tensors to a 3d tensor so that it was able to handle it correctly. Solution is to transform the data dimensionally in some other way (ie transpose).

Comment: I was about to answer. Right, `new_x = tf.transpose(x, perm=(1, 0, 2))` would make it.

Comment: Do you guys want to post this as an answer and accept it too? Some people might also run into this implicit conversion on `tf.Print()` and might find this info valuable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the answer here in case anyone else runs across this problem in the future.

Turns out, a lot of old RNN examples floating around use unstack. However, that turns it into a list of tensors, which dynamic_rnn cannot take as input. The print was converting it from a list of 2d tensors to a 3d tensor so that it was able to handle it correctly. Solution is to transform the data dimensionally in some other way like:

`new_x = tf.transpose(x, perm=(1, 0, 2))` (thanks rvinas)